# How to set 'gain' as Feature Importance measure in feature_importances_ for LightGBM classifer in sklearn:: LGBMClassifier()

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, gbm

I am building a binary classifier model using LGBMClassifer in LightGBM, similar like below :

```
 # LightGBM model
        clf = LGBMClassifier(
            nthread=4,
            n_estimators=10000,
            learning_rate=0.005,
            num_leaves= 45,
            colsample_bytree= 0.8,
            subsample= 0.4,
            subsample_freq=1,
            max_depth= 20,
            reg_alpha= 0.5,
            reg_lambda=0.5,
            min_split_gain=0.04,
            min_child_weight=.05
            random_state=0,
            silent=-1,
            verbose=-1)
```

Next , Fitting My Model on training data

```
     clf.fit(train_x, train_y, eval_set=[(train_x, train_y), (valid_x, valid_y)], 
                eval_metric= 'auc', verbose= 100, early_stopping_rounds= 200)

    fold_importance_df = pd.DataFrame()
    fold_importance_df["feature"] = feats   
    fold_importance_df["importance"] = clf.feature_importances_
```

Output:

```
feature                      importance
feature13                     1108
feature21                     1104
feature11                     774
```

- Everything is good till here , Now I am looking at Feature Importance measure based on this model. So , I am using `feature_importance_()` function to get that (but by default it's gives me feature importance based on `split` )
- While `split` gives me an insight to which feature is used how many times in splits , but I think `gain` would give me a better understanding of features importance.
- Python API of LightGBM booster class  https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html?highlight=importance mentions :

  ```
   feature_importance(importance_type='split', iteration=-1)


   Parameters:importance_type (string, optional (default="split")) – 
   If “split”, result contains numbers 
   of times the feature is used in a model. If “gain”, result contains 
   total gains of splits which use the feature.
   Returns:   result – Array with feature importances.
   Return type:   numpy array`
  ```

Whereas,**Sklearn API** for LightGBM `LGBMClassifier()` does not mention anything [Sklearn API LGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html?highlight=importance#scikit-learn-api), it only has this parameter to this function :

```
feature_importances_
array of shape = [n_features] – The feature importances (the higher, the more important the feature).
```

- My question is how can I get feature importance from `sklearn` version i.e. `LGBMClassifier()` based on `gain` ?

Comment: Simply switch to the original Lgbm

Comment: That doesn't answer my question . Can you explain what do you mean by original LGBM ?An example would be helpful in the answer section

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`feature_importance()` is a method of Booster object in the original LGBM.

The sklearn API exposes the underlying Booster on the trained data through the attribute `booster_` as given in the [API Docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html?highlight=importance#lightgbm.LGBMModel.booster_).

So you can just first access this booster object and then call the `feature_importance()` in the same way as you would do on the original LGBM.

```
clf.booster_.feature_importance(importance_type='gain')
```